# Using classes to drop columns from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, oop

I am working to reduce non-needed columns of data in a data frame but having it work within the confines of OOP. The columns in the dataframe are from 'A' to 'M'.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# columns 'A' 'B' and 'C' are what I want kept
vibe_df = pd.read_csv('C:Location/Document.csv')
vibe_df = vibe_df[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

The above works, however, I want to use OOP

```
import pandas as pd

class MemoryVibes:
    def __init__(self,dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
     
    def keep_only_column(dataframe):
        dataframe = dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

MemoryVibes.keep_only_column(vibe_df)

vibe_df
```

No errors are being thrown up, but all columns are still present. Please advise as my experience with coding is still in the elementary phases.

Comment: You need to drop the columns from `self.dataframe` and then assign the `DataFrame` returned to `self.dataframe`, i.e., `self.dataframe = self.dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]`. 

From the post it isn't clear whether you intend to modify the dataframe you initially passed in or the one you have to pass in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are never mutating the value of `vibe_df`. When you pass the value into `keep_only_column` you are only accessing the data frame and storing the specific rows. Following the code here, the solution closest to the current architecure would be to simply return the access columns:

```py
def keep_only_column(dataframe):
        return dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

That being said, if you have a class that is strictly comprised of static classes with no shared state, it would be a better idea to extract those methods into a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and import the required methods.

A "proper" `OOP` solution would be to to create an instance of the `MemoryVibes` class, modify the `keep_only_column` to mutate the instance state, and access the mutated value there.

```py
class MemoryVibe:
    def __int__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        # self.dataframe = self.dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

    def keep_only_column():
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]

mvibe = MemoryVibe(vibe_df)
mvibe.keep_only_column()

print(mvibe.dataframe)
```

It would also be better tp directly instantiate the value of `self.dataframe` to the only contain the desired columns with `self.dataframe = dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]` in the `__init__` and remove the `keep_only_columns` so you can ensure that you will always have the proper dataframe without needing to call another function after instantiation.

```py
class MemoryVibe:
    def __int__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe[['DateTime', 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: Thanks mate... this solved my ever not solving issue.